# Extracting Images from Word Documents Using Python docx2txt

Tags: python

I am trying to use docx2txt to extract a bunch of images from the same number of word documents (i.e. each word document has one image saved in it, and nothing else; don't ask me how I ended up here). The problem I'm encountering is that the function "process" in docx2txt saves every first image from a particular word file as "image1," the second as "image2," etc. Since I'm iterating through a list of word documents, every time it tries to find an image in the next word document, it saves over the previously titled "image1". My question: is there any way to avoid this issue using the docx2txt package? I've read through their documentation, and it's pretty scarce and does not seem to indicate a way to change the name of the image files you save (i.e. instead of defaulting to "image1," I might be able to save it as "image_n" for n in my list range. Below is my code. Any suggestions/links to further reading would be sincerely appreciated.

```
import docx2txt
import os

path ="whatever the path is"
savepath = "wherever one would want to save this"

files = []
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.docx'):
        files.append(file) 

for i in range(len(files)):
    image = docx2txt.process(path+ "/" +files[i], savepath) ## this is the line that overwrites each new image
```

I understand why it doesn't work, but there doesn't seem to be another way to handle saving images with this package. Once again, any suggestions would be appreciated.

(P.S.: I've already looked at other questions regarding this issue on SO, but they seem to be focused on extracting multiple images from one document, not a single image from multiple documents.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt/blob/c94663234d2882aa75932f9c9973eb5a804df13b/docx2txt/docx2txt.py#L72

it specifies directory, so instead

```
for i in range(len(files)):
    image = docx2txt.process(path+ "/" +files[i], savepath) ## this is the line that overwrites each new image
```

you could specify a separate save path

```
for i in range(len(files)):
    savepath=savepath+str(i)
    image = docx2txt.process(path+ "/" +files[i], savepath) ## this is the line that overwrites each new image
```

Answer (score 0):

My eventual solution: I ended up saving each image in a folder corresponding to the string that also existed in the word document using the following:

```
import docx2txt
import os

path ="path"
savepath = "savepath"

## Collects name information from the word files

files = []
correctedfiles = []
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.docx'):
        files.append(file)

## Checking above    

for x in range(len(files)):
    print(files[x])

## Makes equal folders as exist questions and names them the by their ID

for i in range(len(files)):
    os.chdir(savepath)
    textresult = docx2txt.process(path + "/" + files[i])
    print(textresult)
    correctresult = textresult.replace('June 2019 ', '')
    os.system('mkdir ' + correctresult)

## Saves images based on name in folders     

for i in range(len(files)):
    textresult = docx2txt.process(path + "/" + files[i])
    correctresult = textresult.replace('June 2019 ', '')
    image = docx2txt.process(path+ "/" +files[i], savepath + '/' + correctresult)
```

There are some extra bits dealing with excess words in the title of the word docs (the 'June 2019 ' stuff).